# Cypress-cucumber use embedded steps

Tags: angular, cucumber, cypress, e2e-testing, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am using cypress and cucumber. There is a common folder with steps that are shared.
I want to create a step that consist of few other different steps is there any way how can I achieve it?

Example:

```
And("step1", () => {
...
})

And("step2", () => {
...
})

And("step3", () => {
...
})

And("combined", () => {
step1
step2
step3
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way do this is to have the step call a helper method and have the method call other helper methods. If you follow this approach you remove all the cucumber specific stuff from your problem and you allow yourself the space to customise your solution and make it more robust.

In ruby I would do this as follows

```
module StepHelper
  def step1
  end

  def step2
  end

  def combined
    step1
    step2
  end
end
World StepHelper

And "step 1" do
  step1
end

And "step 2" do
  step2
end

And "combined" do 
  combined
end
```

Note the last scenario implementation, it is much better than

```
And "combined" do
  step1
  step2
end
```

You'll need to translate this to cypress (sorry I can't help you with that)

Comment: i know what you mean we have helpers but we wanted to try it this way. Anyway thanks for your answer

Comment: Nesting steps has been discredited to some degree for over a decade. What happens is that the more you nest (in width and depth) the more unstable you scenarios become and the harder they become to manage. This is because you have to manage multiple levels of complex calls (calling a step is more complex and much harder to follow than calling a method). By all means ignore my advice, but do realise its based on extensive experience of nesting steps and using this better alternative.